# nuget powershell: cant run build independent updates

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I am trying to update a package through the package manager console with a command like this:

```
update-package Package.Name -version 9.27
```

However this does not seem to work because the package has a lot of build information behind it like so:

```
-version 9.27.5146.3567
```

I would like to get the latest build version of package version 9.27 without constantly selecting the lastest build.

So far I have tried:

```
update-package Package.Name -version 9.27.*
update-package Package.Name -version 9.27.*.*
update-package Package.Name -version 9.27 -safe
```

Note: I can't just update to the latest version of Package.Name It has to be specific 9.27.[latest build]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easier way, but this one-liner should work:

```
Update-Package Package.Name -Version ((Find-Package Package.Name -ExactMatch -AllVersions).Versions | where {$_ -like "9.27.*"} | sort | select -Last 1)
```

Comment: This results in `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Version'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:40`